# Front Camera Video Recording iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, ios4, avfoundation

i am trying to record a video from front camera of iPhone 4 using AVFoundation Framework with the help of WWDC samples i got from iPhone developer program. But i  still cant get it to work..the video does not get recorded or mayb saved in my iPhone library...here's the code i am trying to use...it would b really helpful if someone culd help me with the problem i am having??

```
-(void)recordVideo
{

AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self backFacingCamera] error:nil];

AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

[session addInput:videoInput];

[session addOutput:movieFileOutput];

[movieFileOutput release];  


if (![session isRunning])
 {
 [self performSelector:@selector(startRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
 [session startRunning];

 }

}

- (void) startRecording
{
    NSLog(@"start recording");


AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [playVideo connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[[self movieFileOutput] connections]];
if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:[self orientation]]; 
}

[[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self tempFileURL]
                                    recordingDelegate:self];
}
- (void) stopRecording
{
    NSLog(@"stop recording");

    [[self movieFileOutput] stopRecording];
}
- (NSURL *) tempFileURL
{
    NSLog(@"temp file url");
    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath]) {
    NSLog(@"exists");
    }
    [outputPath release];
    return [outputURL autorelease];
}
- (void) setConnectionWithMediaType:(NSString *)mediaType enabled:(BOOL)enabled;
{

    [[playVideo connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[[self movieFileOutput] connections]] setEnabled:enabled];
}

+ (AVCaptureConnection *)connectionWithMediaType:(NSString *)mediaType fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections;
{
    NSLog(@"connection with media type");
    for ( AVCaptureConnection *connection in connections ) {
        for ( AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts] ) {
            if ( [[port mediaType] isEqual:mediaType] ) {
                return [[connection retain] autorelease];
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
@implementation recordVideo (Internal)

- (AVCaptureDevice *) cameraWithPosition:(AVCaptureDevicePosition) position
{
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device position] == position) {
            return device;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
- (AVCaptureDevice *) backFacingCamera
{
    NSLog(@"back");
    return [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
}
- (AVCaptureDevice *) frontFacingCamera
{
    NSLog(@"front ");
    return [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
}

@end
@implementation recordVideo (AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate)

- (void)             captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
                   fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
{
    NSLog(@"did start recording");

}

- (void)              captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
                    fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
                              error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"did finish recording output file");


    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                                        if (error && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(assetLibraryError:forURL:)]) {
                                            [delegate assetLibraryError:error forURL:assetURL];
                                        }
                                    }];
    } 
    else {

        }

    [library release];    


}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are throwing away the errors - how can you debug if you do that?
2. You need to be more specific in what is / is not happening. Which methods are called? What errors are reported by the SDK (if any)? etc...

Answer (score 0):

you have released reference to movieFileOutput in -(void)recordVideo; 
and you are still using released movieFileOutput in - (void) startRecording as well as
other functions.You better not release object that you are using.